# How to retrieve session variables from session?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I want to create session in my controller as:

```
Session["UserName"] = username
```

In my other controller I want to retrieve this name, but when i write:

```
string username = (string)Session["UserName"]
```

it is "null"

### Why is that happening?

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string[] per = MvcA.Controllers.RuleUsers.ValidateUserAndRole(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (per[0]=="true")

            {
                Session["Role"]=per[1];
                Session["UserName"] = model.UserName;

                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Wrong");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }    


  public ActionResult Add(SellsLiveAdd Per)
    {
        string ses = (string)(Session["UserName"]);
.....
```

Edit

Why sometimes i can retrieve Session["UserName"] and sometimes this variable not exist. What going on?

Comment: Paste in some more relevant code please

Comment: The 2 action methods will suffice

Comment: much better... In the Login Method put a breakpoint at Session["Username"].... line and look what model.UserName is ... looks like a binding problem

Comment: Are you sure that `per[0]=="true"` and you actually entered the `if` condition which stores the value in the Session?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov yeah that was my second guess

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, yes, i am sure.
when the variable Session ["UserName"] created, I direct the mouse on the variable and look in the Content section below and see these variables, but when I want to query the data in the other controller in the Content-written "Empty".
And once everything was normal, that is, there was not empty and I was able to retrieve the Session ["UserName"]. But usually it's empty

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `HttpSessionStateBase Controller.Session`?

Try using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"]`.

Further check the `<sessionState timeout="9999" />` in your config?

Hope this helps.